# Working program starts throwing error code for line split

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a super simple code for my wife to be able to keep track of our household pantry inventory. I had it working fine (pulling items from the text file and writing items to it), but then I started to get this weird error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USFBS/Desktop/Pantry_Inventory", line 24, in <module>
    (val, key) = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I hadn't changed anything in my code, so I am quite baffled as to what might have caused this to start. My code is as follows:

```
def add_item():
    item=raw_input("Add the name of the item that you would like to add __")
    quantity=int(raw_input("Add the quantity of the item on hand __"))
    pantry[item]=quantity

def print_pantry():
    pantry_view = [ (v,k) for k,v in pantry.iteritems() ]
    pantry_view.sort() 
    for v,k in pantry_view:
       print "%s: %s" % (k,v)

def use_item():
    item_used=raw_input("Which item did you use? __")
    quantity_used=int(raw_input("How many did you use? __"))
    pantry[item_used]-=quantity_used


pantry={}

pantry_file=open("pantry.txt","r+")


for line in pantry_file:
    **(val, key) = line.split(" ")**
    pantry[key] = int(val)


while True:
    print_pantry()

    print "What would you like to do?"
    decider=int(raw_input("1:Add Item  2:Use Item  3:Exit  _"))

    if decider==3:
        break
    if decider==2:
        use_item()
    if decider==1:
        add_item()

for i in pantry:
    pantry_file.write(str(pantry[i])+" "+str(i)+"\n")

pantry_file.close
```

Any thoughts or advice on the matter that help to clear this up or at least help me to understand why this might be happening would be fantastic (Note: I put the double asterisks for bold around the line in my code that throws the error for reference).

Comment: Can you post an example of your pantry file. It looks like you try to split an empty line.

Comment: I wonder if the pantry file got overwritten, was OK before, but had wrong or missing data after.

Comment: pantry file is merely one line with "5 pasta" in it. It's small, but for test purposes it does the trick (and I did also add more lines for the sake of testing, still can up with the error).

Comment: Look at the content of your pantry file before you run the program and after

Comment: Blank line in your pantry?

Comment: Blank line in my pantry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this issue at least by opening the pantry file on two separate occasions. One for reading and one for writing. By doing this you ensure the file is overwritten and not appended to.

Read

```
with open("pantry.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        (val, key) = line.split(" ")
        pantry[key] = int(val)
```

Write

```
with open("pantry.txt","w") as f:
    for k, v in pantry.iteritems():
        f.write('%d %s' % (v, k))
```

The problem was you were writing back into the same file instance you read from and the result the file was appended to, your manually added newlines created empty lines in the file. You code was not able to handle this as the tuple unpack demands 2 values from the split on each line.

```
(val, key) = line.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is an empty line in the file that you are reading (pantry.txt) and when the for loop gets to this empty line, the loop variable 'line' is being assigned the empty string.

```
>>> ''.split()
[]
>>> a,b = ''.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: with the help of the commenters on the post, I was able to determine that I had, in fact, added blank lines to the `pantry.txt` file. got it all sorted out now. Thank you for the input though, it is greatly appreciated.